# What exactly does the "Featured" mark on blog posts mean?

Tags: support, blog

All blog posts in the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) homepage appear as "Featured", e.g.

> [image: blog homepage with featured blog posts]

What is the meaning of a blog post being "Featured", and impact on visibility on SE sites, if any?

Comment: could this be a (for lack of a better term) feature of the Wordpress blog site platform used to "pin" these posts to the "featured" area on the landing page? (but considering they're on every entry on the front page and not in a single area, I have no idea)

Comment: @user1306322 digging a bit, it appears when there's a `p-featured` class on the container - so looks like it's a per-post setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments have it right (cheers user1306322 and Shadow Wizard). This is a per-post setting (Sticky) that we use to ensure that new posts are at the top of the main page. In practice, we end up featuring almost everything, though there are times where we have a product announcement or something else that we want on the blog, but not above our featured material.

This is a manual setting, so I have to go through older posts and un-sticky them. It's a pretty low priority task, so it usually ends up that we have about a dozen stickied articles before I get around to housekeeping.

Comment: Wait, so when there's an announcement about one of your own products you deliberately want that less visible than fluff pieces and ads?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. :-)

Comment: I think it should be pretty easy to automate this: just set a cron job to run every week removing the sticky on posts that are more than two weeks old.

Comment: @curiousdannii Sometimes, yes. They'll still get syndicated on the right side yellow box, but someone looking to browse the blog won't see them immediately. There are other times that we want to use a blog post as a landing page for either a banner link or an email campaign.

Comment: @S.S.Anne, it's a pretty small effect and easy enough to fix manually, so I don't want to take up engineering time with a request like this.

Comment: Cron jobs are relatively easy to set up if you're already using cron. If written correctly it shouldn't require maintenance.